# Git repo does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: git, repository, git-clone

I would like to set up a git repo without GitHub. On my server I have a initialized a git repo like this:

```
> git init
> git add *
> git commit -m "test"
```

Now I want to clone this repo from my server via SSH (no SSH keys, with password cause it is not possible with SSH keys at my host).

This is what I execute on my local computer:

```
> git clone ssh://user:password@host.com/backend
```

This is what I get:

```
> Cloning into 'backend'... Permission denied, please try again.
> Permission denied, please try again.
> user:password@.host.com: Permission denied
> (publickey,password). fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How can I fix this error and why do I get this error?

Kind regards and Thank You!

Comment: If you have permissions to login to the server, then it's a problem of which git repo you're trying to clone. You have to give the full path to the repository. Right now you're trying to clone `/backend` from the server

Comment: Even if I try to clone /backend/.git I get the same error message..

Comment: Start by eliminating Git from the equation: make sure you can just run `ssh user@host.com` at all.

Comment: @Jan I think you're missing my point - is your `backend` repository located in the root of the harddrive?